# Can I input a newline when PowerShell output the log on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

On mac's terminal. When the command output the log, for example, `adb logcat` output the android log.

I can input an `Enter` key to enter a newline to the output to separate the output to look clearly.

But I can't do this on windows PowerShell terminal.

How can I sperate the output on windows PowerShell terminal.

I will post an gif link to show the situation.

On mac:

[I can input enter to show a new empty line](https://imgpp.com/image/W6mo6)